# Is the product of two normals of a given form also normal?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Say I have a normal probability distribution whose density is proportional to $e^{-\frac{(x-t_1)^2}{a_1}}$ and another to $e^{-\frac{(x-t_2)^2}{a_2}}$

If I create a third density as the one proportional to $e^{-\frac{(x-t_1)^2}{a_1}} \cdot e^{-\frac{(x-t_2)^2}{a_2}}$, is it necessarily normal? The argument I saw for it being true was basically "the exponent is still a quadratic in x", but it seems that normal distributions cannot have any and all quadratics in their exponent...

Comment: You might want to look up "completing the square"

Comment: You can rewrite the product as $e^{-\frac{(x-t_3)^2}{a_3}} \cdot e^c$ for suitable $t_3,a_3,c$ which depend on $t_1,t_2,a_1,a_2$ - for example $a_3=\frac{a_1a_2}{a_1+a_2}$ [you needed $a_1$ and $a_2$ to be positive originally] so the answer will be yes